# Django url multiple parameter

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

It have been from a week that I search without any answer to my problem. I don't know if I proceed in the good way, but I try to have an url that look like this : `article/title/0/search=ad/2017-08-01/2017-08-09/`; where the parameter are (in brace) : `article/{filter}/{page}/search={search}/{date1}/{date2}/`.

My url.py regex is:

`url(r'article/(?P<filter>.+)/(?P<page>\d+)/(?:search=(?P<search>.*)/)?(?:(?P<date1>(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})?)/)(?:(?P<date2>(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})?)/)?$')`

When the value `search`, `date1` and `date2` are fill, my url think that the `{searched word}/2017-08-01/2017-08-09/` is the `search` value.

When  `search`, `date1` and `date2` are empty, my link are like this: `article/title/0/search=///`. When the dates are filled `article/title/0/search=/2017-08-01/2017-08-09/`.

In my template, I need my url to be like this :`{% url "view" filter page search date1 date2 %}`

Can someone help me and correct me if i did it in the wrong way?

**EDIT**

I'll try to re-ask my problem in another ways:

In my template, in have a form which have 3 fields `search, date1 and date2` not required, so they can be None (this is my problem). I have some links that need to change only one of the view parameters `filter, page` and keep the field param in the url.
When the form is POST to my view (which is actually like this `def AllArticle(request, filter, page, search="", date1="", date2="")`), I use them to filter my ArticleModel object (I don't need help for this, already done and work).

According to @Cory_Madden, I never use this method before and I don't know how to use it. I just tried it and django return me a MultiValueDictKeyError.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what is your model and what are you trying to filter or search. Please post your model and your filter requirement more clearly

Comment: Whatever is appended as GET parameter separated with a ´?´ is *not* seen by your ´urls.py´. Only the url itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you use GET parameters. You need to access them from the `request` object. So let's say you have a function based view, this is how you would access any GET parameters appended to your URL:

```
def index(request, name='World'):
    search_param = request.GET['search']
    ...
```

And your url in this case looks like this:

```
url(r'/(?P<name>.*)', views.index)
```

A request path in your address bar would then look like:

```
/Joe?search=search-term
```

And `request.GET['search']` would return `"search-term"`.

Comment: This doesn't work. It send me a MultiValueDictKey Error.

Comment: That most likely means that you're not providing a GET parameter in your URL. Change it to `search_param = request.GET.get('search', '')`